# Why is std::exchange not noexcept?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards

According to the Standard (N4659, §23.2.4, [utility.exchange]), `std::exchange` should do a `std::move` and a `std::forward`:

> `template <class T, class U = T> T exchange(T& obj, U&& new_val);`
>
> *Effects:* Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> T old_val = std::move(obj);
> obj = std::forward<U>(new_val);
> return old_val;
> ```

Both `move` and `forward` are marked as `noexcept`:
(N4659, §23.2.5, [forward]):

> `template <class T> constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept;`
> `template <class T> constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>&& t) noexcept;`
>
> *Returns:* `static_cast<T&&>(t)`.
>
> (...)
>
> `template <class T> constexpr remove_reference_t<T>&& move(T&& t) noexcept;`
>
> *Returns:* `static_cast<remove_reference_t<T>&&>(t)`.

So why isn't `exchange` `noexcept`? Is there some other reason for this or did the committee simply overlook this? Is this being proposed or can I write one?

Comment: `T(T&&)` might be not`noexcept`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `std::swap`, which by default only relies on move constructors and therefore should usually be `noexcept`, `std::exchange` may allocate resources if the new value needs to be copied. While there could probably be a complicated expression for a conditional `noexcept` when `new_val` is a `U&&` and neither the move assignment nor the old value's move throw, it seems nobody has made such a proposal

Answer (score 2):

The code is also using constructors and the assignment operator for type `T`. One of these might throw.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I don't know how did I overlook this :). Shouldn't it be using `is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>` and `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>` in its `noexcept`-specifier then?

Comment: It would be rather complicated as it (optionally) involves a different type `U` that might be convertible to `T`. Or `T` could have a converting constructor from `U`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a non-std version to create `noexcept` move ctors using rvalues only being conditionally `noexcept` with the values you use, you could use this version:

```
namespace estd {

template<class T, class U = T, std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_move_constructible<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value && 
        std::is_assignable<std::remove_reference_t<T>, std::remove_reference_t<U>&&>::value && 
        !std::is_lvalue_reference<U>::value,
    int> = 0    
>
T rval_exchange(T& obj, U&& new_value) noexcept(
    std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value &&
    std::is_nothrow_assignable<std::remove_reference_t<T>, std::remove_reference_t<U>&&>::value
)
{
    T old_value {std::move(obj)};
    obj = std::move(new_value);
    return old_value;
}

} // namespace estd
```

The template is disabled if you use lvalue references as values to be moved in `obj` (i.e. `new_value` has to be an rvalue reference bound to an rvalue), if you use a type T that is not move constructible, or if construction by move doesn't work with that rvalue.

This way, you could define noexcept move ctors. [Demo here](https://ideone.com/Mhposz). The reason why I restricted the function to rvalues only is because, generally, copying isn't `noexcept`, even though is not always the case, and because `exchange` should be used in move ctors, while having it not `noexcept` makes those ctors not `noexcept`, and that's not good for obvious reasons.

```
void do_stuff() noexcept
{ /*...*/ }

class Sample
{
    std::string mBody;
public:
    Sample(const std::string& body = ""): mBody {body} {}

    Sample(const Sample& s): mBody {s.mBody} {
        printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // noexcept
    }

    Sample& operator=(const Sample& s) { 
        mBody = s.mBody; 
        printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // noexcept
        return *this;
    }

    Sample(Sample&& dying) noexcept(
        noexcept(do_stuff()) && 
        noexcept(estd::rval_exchange(dying.mBody, {}))
    ):
        mBody {estd::rval_exchange(dying.mBody, {})}
    {
        do_stuff(); // noexcept
        printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // noexcept
    }

    Sample& operator=(Sample&& dying) noexcept(
        noexcept(do_stuff()) && 
        noexcept(estd::rval_exchange(dying.mBody, {}))
    )
    {
        mBody = estd::rval_exchange(dying.mBody, {});
        do_stuff();
        printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // noexcept
        return *this;
    }

    std::string body() const noexcept {return mBody;}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    Sample rval{"wow such string very content"};
    Sample dummy;
    std::cout << noexcept( Sample(std::move(rval)) ) << std::endl; // prints true
    std::cout << noexcept( dummy = std::move(rval) ) << std::endl; // prints true

    // The rest only to show that move semantics actually work
    Sample f (std::move(rval));             // Calls move ctor
    std::cout << rval.body() << std::endl;  // prints empty line, empty string moved in rval
    std::cout << f.body() << std::endl;     // prints wow such string very content

    // estd::rval_exchange(f, rval); // Fails to compile bc rval is an lvalue reference, template disabled
    std::cout << (estd::rval_exchange(f, std::move(rval))).body() << std::endl; 
    // Ok, calls move ctor and move assignment (in estd::rval_exchange) and 
    // prints wow such string very content
    std::cout << f.body() << std::endl; // empty line, rval (empty) moved in f
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++23 fixes this by adding a conditional `noexcept` specification to `std::exchange` - see [P2401R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2401r0.html)